SPF and DKIM compliance status in google postmaster tool has no details
We have had SPF and DKIM all set up and domain is verified in postmaster tool, however, in the Postmaster tools new dashboard, we are seeing a message "SPF and DKIM authentication Needs work — Set up both SPF and DKIM authentication" without further information provided. Is there a way to find out in which area our SPF and DKIM configuration need more work?
Compliance status
Thank you!
check spf and dkim settings / records, expect to see more details in google postmaster tool that tell us where we should look into about the SPF and DKIM authentication status

This isn't about programming but I would check the records in a different service.  There are many online tools that can verify your SPF, DKIM, and DMARC records.

Thank you for your response! I did check them but no misconfiguration has been found, that's why I am confused. but will keep looking. Sorry posted the question in a wrong place!

try to reduce the amount of DNS lookups when checking the SPF record, for example if the record contains A or MX try to remove them. Leave only the necessary IPs or spf include if you use any cloud services for emails
